# Search schedule not starting indexing

Tags: 2007, search, crawling

I can manually kick off an incremental crawl for my content sources, however the scheduler does not initiate it on its own. I've attached an image of the crawl schedules if that helps.

[image]

I've also checked the ULS logs and event viewer and neither of them have any related errors. Any ideas on what else I can check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hum, maybe the SharePoint Timer Service is down. Check the Windows Service "Windows Sharepoint Services Timer".

Check also the status of SharePoint jobs (on Operation tab on central administration)